# run reduce function before map

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In our scenario , I map the array and produce the result using jsx , but I want the ignore duplicate data before the map operation. so how can I do that? here snipped code may help you :

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from "../Context/Context";
import "./Navbar.css"
import cartImg from "../../cart.png"
import close from "../../close.svg"

export default function Navbar() {
    const { cart, cartReducer } = useContext(Context)

    function getCart(products) {
        return products.map((product, index) =>
            <div key={index} style={{ borderBottom: "1px solid #d5cfcf" }} >
                <img src={product.image} style={{ width: '100%' }} alt="" />
                <div className="cart-info">
                    <div>
                        <img src={close} onClick={() => 
                            cartReducer({ product, type: 'remove' })} style={{ width: 30, paddingLeft: 10 }} alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {product.name}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src={cartImg} style={{ maxWidth: 30 }} alt="" />
                {cart.length > 0 && <span className="badge badge-warning badge-header">{cart.length}</span>}
                <div className="navbar-cart" style={cart.length > 0 ? { width: 150 } : { width: 'fit-content' }}>
                    <h6> {cart.length == 0 ? 'Cart is Empty' : getCart(cart)}</h6>
                </div>
            </a>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

Comment: `return products.reduce(...).map(...)` ? Or more descriptive: `return unique(products).map(...)` and implement `unique` to deduplicate the data.

Comment: good job . we can benefit from the chain capability. tnx and regards

Answer (score 1):

You can remove duplicates by:

```js
const duplicatedData = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,1,1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,1,3,4]

const notDuplicatedData = [...new Set(duplicatedData)]
console.log(notDuplicatedData)
```

So in your case:

```
[...new Set(products)].map((product, index)
```

Comment: Really depends on how each product is represented and created.

Comment: Indeed it does.